# Creating Custom varbinds dictionary using pysnmp

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am using sendVarbinds from pysnmp to send traps with custom MIBs
e.g.

```
 def sendTrap(self, trapName, trapObjects):
     mibViewController = view.MibViewController(self.snmpEngine.getMibBuilder()) 
     ntfOrg = ntforg.NotificationOriginator()
     ntfOrg.snmpContext = self.snmpContext

     ntfOrg.sendVarBinds(
         self.snmpEngine,
         'my-notification',  # notification targets
         None, '',  # contextEngineId, contextName

         rfc1902.NotificationType(
             trapName,
             objects=trapObjects # <-- how to construct this?
         ).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
     )
```

The NotificationType requires a dictionary of varbinds , having object key value pair .
I would like to populate the object dictionary key and value from a json object .Right now I am doing it like this for each trap.

```
def function1():
    trapName = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('MY-MIB', 'ServerPart')
    trapObjects = {
        ('MY-MIB', 'ServerIP'): event.get_ServerIP(),
        ('MY-MIB', 'ServerPartName'): event.get_ServerPartName(),
        ('MY-MIB', 'ServerState'): event.get_ServerState()
    }

def function2():
    trapName = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('MY-MIB', 'ServerMemory')
    trapObjects = {
        ('MY-MIB', 'ServerIP'): event.get_ServerIP(),
        ('MY-MIB', 'ServerMemoryAv'): event.get_ServerMemoryAv()
    }
```

But I want to have a single function to create the traps without checking the varbinds and fill them using the JSON object? Say I run a loop on dictionary items().

My flow is like this.

Client --- event JSON object ----> Trap daemon ---- traps -----> Manager

This is an example of the JSON object which comes from client

```
my_event('ServerPart', '10.22.1.1', '44', '1', host, port)
my_event('ServerMemory', '10.22.1.1', '100MB', host, port)
```

Is there any example which can be followed?

Comment: regarding "_This is an example of the JSON object which comes from client:_" `my_event('ServerPart', '10.22.1.1', '44', '1', host, port)` - it looks nothing like JSON.

Comment: Sorry ....    here is the json format 

{"ServerIP": "10.22.1.1", "ServerPartName": "22", "EventType": "ServerPart", "ServerState": "40"}

Answer (score 0):

Each notification type requires its own set of managed objects (`trapOpjects`) to be included with the notification. I suppose the mapping of *event name* -> *notification type* is 1-to-1 and you can re-constract event field getter from field name.

Then what's remaining is to map event and its parameters to notification type and managed objects:

```
eventParamsToManagedObjectsMap = {
    'ServerPart': {  # <- notification type
        'ServerIP': 'get_ServerIP',  # <- trap objects
                                     # e.g. to populate ServerIP,
                                     # call get_serverIP()
        # ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, to build such map you could try something along these lines:

```
notificationType = 'ServerMemory'  # on input you should have all
                                   # event or notification types

trapObjectIdentity = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('MY-MIB', notificationType)
trapObjectIdentiry.resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
trapObjectNames = trapObjectIdentity.getMibNode().getObjects()

eventParamsToManagedObjectsMap = defaultdict(dict)

for mibName, mibObjectName in trapObjectNames:
   eventParamsToManagedObjectsMap[notificationType][mibObjectName] = 'get_' + mibObjectName
```

Once you have this map, you should be able to build notifications out of events uniformly within a single function.

Comment: after this how should I use 

ntfOrg.sendVarBinds(
    self.snmpEngine,
    'my-notification',  # notification targets
    None, '',  # contextEngineId, contextName

    rfc1902.NotificationType(
    trapName,
    objects=trapObjects
    ).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
)

objects=trapObjects  seems to be the problematic part

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try something like this (untested):

```
def get_notification(trapName, **kwargs):
    return rfc1902.NotificationType(
        trapName,
        objects={('MY-MIB', k): v for k, v in kwargs.items()}
    }
```

Assuming `json_data` is already a Python dict (if it is a string call `json.loads(json_data)` in order to parse it) you can call it like this:

```
 ntfOrg.sendVarBinds(
     self.snmpEngine,
     'my-notification',  # notification targets
     None, '',  # contextEngineId, contextName
     get_notification(**json_data).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
 )
```

Comment: in get_notification(eventvals).resolveWithMib(mibViewController) should I pass trapName ?

Comment: Not necessary if you always have a key named trapName in json_data.

Comment: Okay this seems to have helped me in this context ... thanks